# I upgraded spring boot to 3.1.1 version and I get this error from Redis NOAUTH HELLO must be called with the client

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis

I recently upgraded my spring boot project to version 3.1.1, I configured the Redis like the following:

```
@Bean
public ReactiveRedisConnectionFactory redisFirstConnectionFactory() {
    var redisConf = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration();
    redisConf.setHostName(host);
    redisConf.setPort(port);
    redisConf.setPassword(password);
    redisConf.setDatabase(0);
    return new LettuceConnectionFactory(redisConf,
            LettuceClientConfiguration
                    .builder()
                    .commandTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
                    .build());
}


@Bean
public ReactiveStringRedisTemplate redisTemplate(ReactiveRedisConnectionFactory cf) {
    return new ReactiveStringRedisTemplate(cf);
}
```

But when I start the application I get the following Exception:

```
 2023-07-17 13:59:17,781 [boundedElastic-1] WARN  org.springframework.boot.actuate.data.redis.RedisReactiveHealthIndicator [,] - Redis health check failed
org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException: Unable to connect to Redis
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory$ExceptionTranslatingConnectionProvider.translateException(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:1602)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory$ExceptionTranslatingConnectionProvider.getConnection(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:1533)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory$SharedConnection.getNativeConnection(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:1358)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory$SharedConnection.getConnection(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:1341)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory.getSharedReactiveConnection(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:1083)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory.getReactiveConnection(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:479)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory.getReactiveConnection(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:105)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoSupplier.call(MonoSupplier.java:67)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSubscribeOnCallable$CallableSubscribeOnSubscription.run(FluxSubscribeOnCallable.java:227)
    at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:68)
    at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:28)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException: Unable to connect to localhost/<unresolved>:6379
    at io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException.create(RedisConnectionException.java:78)
    at io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException.create(RedisConnectionException.java:56)
    at io.lettuce.core.AbstractRedisClient.getConnection(AbstractRedisClient.java:350)
    at io.lettuce.core.RedisClient.connect(RedisClient.java:216)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.StandaloneConnectionProvider.lambda$getConnection$1(StandaloneConnectionProvider.java:112)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:364)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.StandaloneConnectionProvider.getConnection(StandaloneConnectionProvider.java:112)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory$ExceptionTranslatingConnectionProvider.getConnection(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:1531)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: io.lettuce.core.RedisCommandExecutionException: NOAUTH HELLO must be called with the client already authenticated, otherwise the HELLO AUTH <user> <pass> option can be used to authenticate the client and select the RESP protocol version at the same time
    at io.lettuce.core.internal.ExceptionFactory.createExecutionException(ExceptionFactory.java:147)
    at io.lettuce.core.internal.ExceptionFactory.createExecutionException(ExceptionFactory.java:116)
    at io.lettuce.core.protocol.AsyncCommand.completeResult(AsyncCommand.java:120)
    at io.lettuce.core.protocol.AsyncCommand.complete(AsyncCommand.java:111)
    at io.lettuce.core.protocol.CommandWrapper.complete(CommandWrapper.java:63)
    at io.lettuce.core.protocol.CommandHandler.complete(CommandHandler.java:747)
    at io.lettuce.core.protocol.CommandHandler.decode(CommandHandler.java:682)
    at io.lettuce.core.protocol.CommandHandler.channelRead(CommandHandler.java:599)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:442)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:440)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollStreamChannel$EpollStreamUnsafe.epollInReady(AbstractEpollStreamChannel.java:800)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:499)
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:397)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    ... 1 more
```

I can connect to Redis with that password using RedisInsight.
Redis version 6.2.6

If you need anything please tell me to add to question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why spring boot was trying to configure it's redis using auto configuration

I have to add this to application.properties

```
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.redis.RedisAutoConfiguration
```